# How can I add multiple Moving averages with pine script version 4?

Tags: pine-script

I want to add different types of MAs (sma, ema, wma,etc) with inputs for periods and sources( e.g High, low,  etc) for each indicator. Please I just need a guide. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search the Public Library. There are many examples. This is one: https://www.tradingview.com/script/8AUuFonD-5-MAs-w-alerts-LucF/

Comment: Thanks. I saw it.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started

```
priceData = input(title="Price Data", type=source, defval=close)
emaValONE = input(title="EMA 1", type=integer, defval=5)
emaValTWO = input(title="EMA 2", type=integer, defval=13)
emaValTHREE = input(title="EMA 3", type=integer, defval=200)
emaValFOUR = input(title="EMA 4", type=integer, defval=800)
emaValFIVE = input(title="EMA 5", type=integer, defval=3200)

// Calculate moving averages
emaONE = ema(priceData, emaValONE)
emaTWO = ema(priceData, emaValTWO)
emaTHREE = ema(priceData, emaValTHREE)
emaFOUR = ema(priceData, emaValFOUR)
emaFIVE = ema(priceData, emaValFIVE)

plot(emaONE, color = red, title="5 EMA",style = line, linewidth = 1, transp = 0)
plot(emaTWO, color = yellow, title="13 EMA",style = line, linewidth = 1, transp = 0)
plot(emaTHREE, color = white, title="200 EMA",style = line, linewidth = 1, transp = 0)
plot(emaFOUR, color = blue, title="800 EMA",style = line, linewidth = 1, transp = 0)
plot(emaFIVE, color = fuchsia, title="3200 EMA",style = line, linewidth = 1, transp = 0)
```

Let me know if this helps.